# Microsoft Report dependencies

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-reporting

What are the tools or the dependencies needed to run the windows application contains reports of Microsoft's 2010 and 2012

is Microsoft Report 2012 run time enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms

you will find them in **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer**

Comment: do i need any additional prerequisites to setup them on client machine ?

Comment: yes you will need to run ReportViewer.exe you will find it in 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer

when you deploy your application select from prerequisites 
> Microsoft visual studio 2010 report viewer